# Delete By Id MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using BeginCollectionItem with MVC 5 for adding and removing rows whenever.

One issue I'm having is with the delete function, I followed an online tutorial 
which specified using #divId:first which seems to indicate deleting the first row whenever. This is no good for me, and wouldn't make sense to an end user.

As I'm using BCI I want to delete these from the html DOM so they won't have database Ids.

How do I delete by the Id of the model, this apparently (I think I read somewhere) is automatically generated by BCI?

**Delete Function in the main view**

```
$('#deleterow').live('click', function () {
            $(this).parents('#newRow:first').remove();
            return false;
        });
```

**Partial View with rows I want to delete by Id**

```
@model  Mvc.Models.Project
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("something"))
{
    <div id="newRow">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)

        <a href="#" id="deleterow">Delete</a>
    </div>
}
```

**Update 2**

When viewing the rendered html the data-action attribute renders as 0 for all objects so the JQuery can't and won't delete a row/object from the view.

**Update**

Instead of the check box I want to use the Delete link button, I assume this is possible? Not very familiar with jQuery but it is something I intend to look at, fairly new to MVC too but this is what I have so far:

**Main View**

```
<h3>Students</h3>
<div id="newStudent">
    @foreach(var Student in Model.students)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("_Student");
    }
</div>
<input type="button" id="addStudent" name="addStudent" value="Add Student"/>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#addStudent').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: 'School/AddNewStudent'
        }).success(function (partialView) {
            $('#newStudent').append(partialView);
        });
    });

    $('#newStudent').on('click', '.deleteStudent', function () {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        if (id === 0) { // assumes Id is integer
            $(this).closest('.studentRow').remove();
        }
        else { // existing item - controller to delete from Db
            var url = '@Url.Action("action", "controller")';
            $.post(url, { ID: id }, function (response) {
                if (response) {
                    $(this).closest('.studentRow').remove();
                }
            }).fail(function (response) {
                // display error message
            });
        }
    });
    </script>
}
```

**Partial View**

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("students"))
{
    <div id="studentRow">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)

        <a href="#" class="deleteStudent" data-action="@Model.Id">Delete</a>
    </div>
```

}

**Controller**

```
public class SchoolController : Controller
{
    // GET: School
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var newSchool = new School();

        return View(newSchool);
    }

    public ActionResult AddNewStudent()
    {
        var student = new Student();
        return PartialView("_Student", student);
    }
    [HttpPost, ActionName("DeleteStudent")]
    public ActionResult DeleteStudent(School school)
    {
        foreach(var student in school.students.Where(s => !s.isDeleted))
        {
            return View(school.students);
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly `.live()` was depreciated in jquery-1.7 and removed in 1.9. Use `.on()` instead. Next your generating invalid html by generating duplicate `id` attributes for the 'delete' link, which also means you will only ever be able to delete the first item and you never be able to delete newly added items because you are not using event delegation. Note also the `BeginCollectionItem` does not _ automatically generate the models ID_. All it does is add a prefix to the property name which includes an indexer value based on a `guid` so that the items can be bound to a collection on post back.

The link in your partial partial needs a class name and should store the `Id` value so it can be easily accessed in the script.

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("students"))
{
    <div id="studentRow">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.isDeleted) // not sure what the point of the data- attribute is
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
        <a href="#" class="deleteStudent" data-id="@Model.Id">Delete</a>
    </div>
}
```

Then your script needs to be (note the `id="newStudent"` for the enclosing `<div>` is confusing since you `foreach` loop is generating the html for existing items)

```
$('#newStudent').on('click', '.deleteStudent', function() { // use event delegation
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    if (id == 0) { // assumes property Id is typeof int
        // Its a new item so just remove from the DOM
        $(this).closest('.studentRow').remove();
    } else {
        // Its an existing item so call controller to delete it from the database
        var url = '@Url.Action(""DeleteStudent", "School")';
        $.post(url, { ID: id }, function(response) {
            if(response) {
                // The student was successfully deleted
                $(this).closest('.studentRow').remove();
            }
        }).fail(function (response) {
            // Oops, something went wrong - display error message?
        });
    }
});
```

And the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DeleteStudent(int ID)
{
    // delete the student from the database based on the ID and signal success
    return Json(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - now I'm getting an error in relation to the JQuery 'Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.' Having looked at it I've found that it's because of cross AJAX calls, I don't know why this is happening as it wasn't happening yesterday, still occurs if I remove the deleteStudent JQuery - is this common, do you know what could be causing it? Will update question with up-to-date code - thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is anything in the code I gave which could possibly cause that. Is it happening in the 'delete' function or in the 'add' function (I notice you have `async: false,` - not sure why you have that. Also I really dont understand what the point of the hidden input of the `IsDeleted` property is - the 'delete' function deletes it - it no longer exists - so it just seems a bit pointless.

Comment: Apologies - yes it is for your answer, will remove it, as it's an example I've just re-made it and it doesn't have the same issue, the only issue I can see now is it won't delete anything as the 'Id = 0' in the rendered html for any added objects. Will update question and remove red herring.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The `data-id="@Model.Id"` in the link (as part of the partial) stores the Id of the model (which for new items will be zero assuming your Id property is typeof `int` - so `var id = $(this).data('id');` sets `id=0` which you then test with `if (id == 0)`. Have you used my code as is?

Comment: You need to read my answer more carefully - its `<a href="#" class="deleteStudent" data-id="@Model.Id">Delete</a>`, not `<a href="#" id="deleteStudent" data-action="deleteStudent">Delete</a>`

Comment: Yeah, should I not? The data-id does assume int correctly, but then there are multiple models in the partial all with the id of 0, so how is it meant to delete one that's zero? Deletion from the database is useful, but not using that in this example so haven't added anything for that as it shouldn't be hit.

Comment: Sorry that came about when I edited the q, I will update the q as that partial isn't representative of the code.

Comment: I assume you completely misunderstanding my code. When you click the 'add' button, your generating a new partial based on a new `Student` whose `Id` value is `0`. This 'new' student has never been saved to the database so it does not need to be deleted - all that needs to happen is it needs to be removed from the DOM (which is why if checks if its a new student by testing if `Id==0`.

Comment: An existing student however needs to be deleted from the database, so if `Id != 0`, then the code first calls a controller method to delete it from the database, and then assuming an exception was not thrown it is removed from the DOM. This is also the reason you `IsDeleted` property is pointless. When you post back the form to save any edits, there are no items that need to be deleted (they already have been)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76433/discussion-between-jammandtea-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 4):

What I have done is created a `IsDeleted` Property in `Model/ViewModel`, Put it in the Row as a Hidden Field, And also have a delete button against each `Row`

```
 using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Contacts"))
    {
        <div class="row mt-10">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.isDeleted, new { data_is_deleted = "false" })

.......Removed HTML

        <div class="col-md-1">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" data-action="removeItem" title="remove" style="cursor:pointer"></span>
        </div>
```

Then add this jQuery a JavaScript file. *(Note: Don't add this to the Row Partial View, I add it in the View that calls the Row Partial View)*

You might have to edit this jQuery to match your HTML structure, The goal in this jQuery is to update the IsDeleted field to either true or false and then Disable the other Input fields

```
$(document).on('click', '*[data-action="removeItem"]', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var btn = $(this);
    var row = btn.closest('.row');
    var parent = btn.parent();
    var checkBox = parent.siblings('*[data-is-deleted]');

    var checkBoxVal = checkBox.val();
    if(checkBoxVal == 'False' || checkBox.val() == 'false'){
        checkBox.val('true');
        row.find('input, textarea, select').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
    } else {
        checkBox.val('false');
        row.find('input, textarea, select').attr("readonly", false);
    }
    checkBoxVal = checkBox.val();
});
```

This is what your view will look like:

[image]

When post Back to Controller:

```
foreach (var contact in contacts.Where(s => !s.isDeleted))
{
   // New and Updated Items
}

foreach (var contact in myModel.Where(s => s.isDeleted && s.Id!= 0))
 {              
    // Deleted Items
// You don't have to delete Items where Id == 0, Bcz they are not in the DB.
// Just some Item added to the View and then deleted without Save
  }
```

Deleted Items will be disabled: *Note: You can Hide them by editing the above jQuery*

[image]

**EDIT A:**
Actual controller code is something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveStudent(Student model){


// Save model items

// Then Save the List of Items like this:

    foreach (var contact in model.myListItems.Where(s => !s.isDeleted))
    {
       // New and Updated Items
    }

    foreach (var contact in model.myListItems.Where(s => s.isDeleted && s.Id!= 0))
     {              
        // Deleted Items
    // You don't have to delete Items where Id == 0, Bcz they are not in the DB.
    // Just some Item added to the View and then deleted without Save
      }


}
```

Comment: Looks slick, will give it a shot and get back to you, thanks.

Comment: You might have to edit the jQuery to match your HTML structure.

Comment: Am doing, having a little trouble as I want to change it to be an anchor tag/link rather than a check box, will update the question in a minute if you could offer some assistance that would be fab, cheers for your help.

Comment: @JammAndTea I have edited my answer, If you are using **BeginCollectionItem** and the User adds a New Item (dynamically). it won't have an id. Don't display the button if id == 0